# In sftp i am not able to copy all files in ksh sctipt

Tags: shell, unix, ftp, sftp, ksh

I am connecting thru sftp in shell script file and trying to `-mget` all files from multiple directories like below:

```
   sshpass -p $password sftp -oBatchMode=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -b - $user@$host 1>$currentdir/ftp.log << !
    cd /DAILY_FEEDS/abc/in/xml/
    -mget *.*
    cd /DAILY_FEEDS/abc/in/pdf/
    ls * tp_pdf.lst
    -mget *.*
    cd /DAILY_FEEDS/abc/in/images/
    -mget *.*
    cd /DAILY_FEEDS/xyz/in/xml/
    -mget *.*
    cd /DAILY_FEEDS/xyz/in/pdf/
    -mget *.*
    cd /DAILY_FEEDS/xyz/in/images/
    -mget *.*
    cd /DAILY_FEEDS/xyz/in/pdfmetaxml/
    -mget *.*
    bye
!
```

When any file is empty then process skip onward. in above scenario if `/DAILY_FEEDS/abc/in/images/` there are no image and later in `/DAILY_FEED/xyz/in/xml/` directory having files then its not picking after `abc/in/images`.

Comment: I have test that if i place some files in all folders then its all copying and working fine..

Answer (score 0):

You have to check initially any files exists inside the folder or not.If files exists then use "mget" to download files ,otherwise go to next folder.

"mget" working for me.

Comment: Hi.   Consider using markdown syntax to highlight you ```code syntax```